# Error in android application extending BaseAdapter and using Asyncktask

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

i  have android application that need connection between android and mysql database using php  the application work perfect. only the display user action  do not work this method display  the user in a list with some data.

can anyone help me to fix this error ??

## the result of the added code is

```
04-14 23:17:57.766: D/this from internet(2367): usersList.get(position).getDate() is null
```

## LogCat Error

```
   04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at com.devleb.loginDemo.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:60)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-14 21:59:22.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1951):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

## list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/uid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:text="text view"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCreateDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## User.java

```
package com.devleb.loginDemo;

import java.util.HashMap;

//@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class User extends HashMap<String, String> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    String name;
    String date;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

## CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.devleb.loginDemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static ArrayList<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();

    // private static ArrayList name, date;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    String[] userName;
    Date[] createdDate;
    Context context;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<User> result, Context c) {
        usersList = result;
        context = c;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return usersList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return usersList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = null;

        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView txtCreateDate = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.txtCreateDate);

        txtCreateDate.setText(usersList.get(position).getDate());

        TextView txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);

        txtName.setText(usersList.get(position).getName());
        return row;
    }

}
```

## UserListActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.loginDemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UserListActivity extends ListActivity {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList;

    // **** added from internt*************///
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    ArrayList<User> arrayList_userList;
    ListView lvUsers;
    // **** added from internt*************///

    private static String url_display_user = "http://10.0.3.2/android_connect/display_user.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";

    private static final String TAG_USERS = "userlist";

    private static final String TAG_USER = "user";
    private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";

    // private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // employees JSONArray
    JSONArray users = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);

        // usersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        new getUserList().execute();

        // getListView
        lvUsers = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        lvUsers.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                // String id = ((TextView)
                // view.findViewById(R.id.uid)).getText()
                // .toString();

                // Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), StatusList.class);
                // in.putExtra(TAG_ID, uid);

                // startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }

    class getUserList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            UserListActivity.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> parametres = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_display_user,
                    "GET", parametres);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Users: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS);

                    // looping through All Users
                    for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String user = c.getString(TAG_USER);
                        String cdate = c.getString(TAG_DATE).toString();

                        // creating new HashMap
                        User map = new User();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_USER, user);
                        map.put(TAG_DATE, cdate);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList

                        // usersList.add(map);

                        arrayList_userList.add(map);
                    }
                    // ***********************************//
                    // From the internet

                    // arrayList_userList = new
                    // ArrayList<User>(usersList.value())

                    // **********************************//

                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {

                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            if (result != null) {

                UserListActivity.this
                        .setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                /*
                 * ListAdapter adapter = new
                 * SimpleAdapter(UserListActivity.this, usersList,
                 * R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_USER }, new
                 * int[] { R.id.uid, R.id.name }); // updating listview
                 * setListAdapter(adapter);
                 */
                lvUsers.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(arrayList_userList,
                        getBaseContext()));

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.user_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is line 60 of `CustomAdapter`?

Comment: this line of code **txtCreateDate.setText(usersList.get(position).getDate().toString());**

Comment: Post your R.layout.list_item as well.

Comment: @ uDEVEL i will add the layout

Comment: In your `User` class, the `getDate` method is returning null.

Comment: @ Naddy but the return type is string how it return null ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't setDate(), so getDate() is null.

```
                    // creating new HashMap
                    User map = new User();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_USER, user);
                    map.put(TAG_DATE, cdate);
```

I don't see any use of HashMap is any of the code.  But for testing, just leave this here.

Add 
        map.setName(user);
        map.setDate(cdate);

That's it.

Comment: and what about the TAGS you told me to put it in the user class  so what i do about it ??

Comment: Leave everything and add the two lines, for demonstration purpose.

Comment: you are really a grate person now i understand what you mean by throwing the hashmap. thank you. but i still have one question if you can help me with it

Comment: But do you still get the npe?

Comment: i did not understand your last comment .. my question is about the list view now it work but i get the list view with a lot of separation between first row and second row.  each row seams like a square. how to fix that ?

Comment: I see.  That is another question.  Let me know the link after you create it.

Answer (score 0):

Put this

```
Log.d(TAG, txtCreateDate == null ? "txtCreateDate is null" : usersList.get(position) == null ? "usersList.get(position) is null" : usersList.get(position).getDate() == null ? "usersList.get(position).getDate() is null" : "nothing is null");
```

Before

```
 txtCreateDate.setText(usersList.get(position).getDate().toString());
```

Also, don't you need to initialize your usersList?

Comment: Sorry, be more specific please.
"usersList.get(position).getDate() is null"?

Comment: the getDate method is a method from User class this method must return the values from mysql database so  is my code wrong ???

Comment: First, did you initialize `arrayList_userList`?

Second, what's the log message you got from my code?  Post it.

Third, why use toString() when your getDate() returns a string already.

Comment: first i did second i will add the result in my question third i deleted the toSring()

Comment: Ok I got it.  You are using your `public class User extends HashMap<String, String>` wrong.
Why need to use HashMap?

You didn't even called setDate() ever.

Comment: You can just use your user as object.
Then user.setName(user"?username or user") , user.setDate(cdate), and probably add a field for user id.

Comment: to Add in the UserListActivity that contain the getDisplayuser method  the TAG and the String than add the map to the list is this a wrong way to do it ??

Comment: I don't it's right way.
But first of all, you didn't call setName, then how do you expect to get anything from getName()?

Comment: For your case, I think you should use a Hashmap of users, instead of an Arraylist of hashmaps.
Your User should be a simple Object and you use the getter and setter.
UserID will be the key to the Hashmap.

Comment: if i use the user as an object i got an error when i try to add the hashMap to the arrayList<User> IT DISPLAY THIS ERROR **The method add(User) in the type ArrayList<User> is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<String,String>)**

Comment: Forget what I said.

By looking at your code, you don't even need userID, why bother with hashmap?

Throw away the hashmap, just use user, and don't use put, use the setter.

Comment: the last comment i did not understand it and if ii do not use the HashMap how i will be able to put in the list the TAG that i get from the mysql and the String that i got from jsonObject after looping ??

Comment: You meant TAG_ID?  Why not add that as a field in User?

Comment: i meant TAG_ID- TAG_USER- TAG_DATE and i asked about how to put all these in a list view if i do not use the hashmap ??  so what you say is i create a public static field of these TAGS  in the user class ?? then how to use it in the UserListActivity class to display the result in list... sorry for these question but i am getting a huge amount of experience and knowledge by asking you thank you fro all your replies

Comment: Change map.put(TAG_DATE, cdate) to map.setDate(cdate)

Comment: and what about the user Class ?? i put the TAGs in this class and in  i throw the hashMap and use the User instead ?? can you show me the code how to fix it ???

Comment: Let me create new answer.

Comment: i changed my code but still get error so  i will add the change to my question can you tel me how to fix it ??

Comment: this is the [new question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072869/my-list-view-in-android-seams-like-a-square-how-to-fix-that-and-what-is-the-erro)