# my list view in android seems like a square how to fix that and what is the error?

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I have an android application that uses `php` and `mysql` and after fetching the from the database, the result are displayed in a listView that is handled by a BaseAdapter.

The problem is that the rows in the list seem like a square.

[image]

can anyone tell me where the mistake is in the xml files ???

## activity_user_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background_1">
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

## list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/uid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text view"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCreateDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove the background of your relative layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the background image from activity_user_list.